# Windows C++ How can I call a blocking read from one thread to another?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, communication

I have two classes in C++ (Windows, Visual Studio 2010) each running a different thread, and I want to send messages between them in a simple way. The idea is that the main calls a read on class2, waits for class2 to get the data, and then main class receives it and continues - something like a socket, but between two class/thread on the same program. Can this be done?

Example:

```
class MyClass(){
    ...
    void run(){...}; //runs a thread here that collects data from a network socket
};



int main(){
    MyClass *mc = new MyClass();
    mc->run();
    ...
    mc->receiveData(); //returns a value AFTER the class gets a hold of it, and blocks in the meantime...
}
```

Is there any simple way to do this? Kind of like creating a socket, and reading from it, it won't return until it receives the packet/data from the network, except I want a class to do this on the local system. Thanks!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem

Comment: `something like a socket, but between two class/thread on the same program. Can this be done?` -- you could do it with a socket.... nothing wrong with sockets within the same program.

Comment: A coroutine model sounds like a good fit.  Then you only need 1 thread.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want a thread-safe queue to put your messages on.

Check out the 'Parallel containers and objects' in the Microsoft [Parallel Patterns Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492418.aspx).  That page has an example showing the use of `concurrent_vector`.

Answer (score 1):

Create the thread and call a join() on the thread.  (Google that).  Thread joins will allow you to spawn off a thread for processing and indicate that once main reaches the join, it should wait for the thread it is joining to complete.  You can return a value from the thread when it returns at the join statement so main can know the result if you need it.